# Ruby puts not putting

Tags: ruby

I am answering the following question:

> Q3: Write a method, is_prime?, that takes a number num and returns
>   true if it is prime and false otherwise.
>
> You may wish to use the modulo operation: 5 % 2 returns the remainder
>   when dividing 5 by 2: 1. If num is divisible by i, then num % i == 0.
>   (You would not be expected to already know about modulo for the
>   challenge)

but I get no answer back. My final "puts" doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
# Q3 method is_prime?

def is_prime? (num)

  i = 2

  while i <= num

    is_divisble = ((num%i) == 0)

    if is_divisble
      return false 
    end

    i+=1

  end

  # is not divisible
  return true

end

puts 'select a number greater than one and see if it\'s prime'
num = gets.chomp.to_i
puts is_prime?(num)
```

Comment: After you type `num = gets.chomp.to_i`, are you tying a number and then hitting `Enter`? You need to do that before you execute your last `puts` statement.

Comment: I am pressing Enter. The program exists after I press Enter after typing in the num.

Comment: As a note, if you use double quotes, you won't have to escape the single ones.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  Don't make us guess.  Please tell us--in the question itself--_exactly_ what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code prints fine. However, it always prints `true`. Remedy: change `while i <= num`
to `while i < num` .

Comment: It wasn't printing until I fixed it the way you suggested. `while i <= num` thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
i <= num
```

It is your mistake :).
Your code will increment i until i == num so num%i will always be true at the end.

Just replace it with

```
i < num
```